# Error when run command (start IOUFlow iouValue: 99, otherParty: "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US") in (hello world 1)

Tags: blockchain, corda

i have followed all the steps in hello world 1

https://docs.corda.net/hello-world-template.html

https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin

but when run this command
i have faced this error:

[ERROR] 20:14:21+0200 [Node thread-1] proxies.ExceptionSerialisingRpcOpsProxy.log - Error during RPC invocation [errorCode=ue63ey, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.0/ue63ey] {actor_id=internalShell, actor_owning_identity=O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=ef20094f-ecea-4004-b6dc-e687f88fdce9, invocation_id=c783d17e-1a70-4ec9-93ca-cb08714afac7, invocation_timestamp=2019-03-12T18:14:18.869Z, origin=internalShell, session_id=e7787152-785d-47fc-a5a6-e8893a730942, session_timestamp=2019-03-12T18:14:02.935Z, thread-id=221, tx_id=E38133ECBB005885B0DFD501A214C928AB67C34188C7B0F0BD659825487A27AF}

I can't understand the meaning of the error

how can solve this error ?

Answer (score 3):

It got resolved by adding @BelongsToContract annotation on IOUState class. Thanks to gerferra for helping  :)

```java
@BelongsToContract(TemplateContract.class)
public class IOUState implements ContractState {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means the real exception can be found in the node logs.

We will probably adjust this in a future release so all exceptions are sent back to the RPC client instead of just some of them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. The node logs report:

> net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionVerificationException$TransactionRequiredContractUnspecifiedException:
>   State of class com.template.IOUState does not have a specified owning
>   contract. Add the @BelongsToContract annotation to this class to
>   ensure that it can only be bundled in a TransactionState with the
>   correct contract.

Adding the annotation to the IOUState class solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Thread-19 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] custom.ThrowableSerializer.fromProxy - Unexpected exception de-serializing throwable: net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionVerificationException$TransactionRequiredContractUnspecifiedException. Converting to CordaRuntimeException. [errorCode=39z9vh, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.0/39z9vh]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
|
|
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionVerificationException$TransactionRequiredContractUnspecifiedException., parameter state
    at net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionVerificationException$TransactionRequiredContractUnspecifiedException.(TransactionVerificationException.kt) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]